# It there any way to create a curved website menubar in pure css?

Tags: css

We can use CSS `border-radius` to create a rounded corner. But can we create the below shape in pure CSS?

[image]
I did try using `border-radius`, but I don't know how to create the shape. It would be grateful if there are   any css codeings. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You'll need to use an SVG path, probably - but you can embed an SVG path in a `data:` URI inline in a `*.css` file FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

Working worh SVG paths sounds great.
What about drawing a…

**Bezier Curve**

You could combine a Bezier and a border-radius to achieve the bottom-right of the requested form.

Hey, just found: `clip-path`

https://jaketrent.com/post/create-bezier-curve-clip-path/

Unless more symmetry is a good thing, then just the Bezier.

[Bezier curve in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946272/bezier-curve-in-css)

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/func_cubic-bezier.php

**Canvas**

Another idea, but fails to CSS-only.

Let me think…

**Bicycle Approach**

I‘ve just invented that one I suppose ^^
Drawing 2 absolute  positioned circles (rounded div‘s) plus `::after` to mask parts of the circles …applying a ‘rotate’ transformation plus a position adjustment to the ::after pseudo element (maybe increasize to adjust the curve until it‘s a match ‍♂️

I won‘t correct ‚increasize‘ typo, I ve just invented a new word too.